# Spark NullPointerException nested field access in filter

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am a newbie for spark. I got `NullpointerException` at the line `.filter(_.getStatusStandardizedData.getIsActive.getValue)`
today

```scala
val activeStzOrganizations: Dataset[OrganizationStandardizedData] = DataSources.stzOrganization().asDataset
    .filter(_.getStatusStandardizedData.getIsActive.getValue)
```

It looks like either `getStatusStandardizedData` or `getIsActive` could be `null`.

Is there a smart way to make it work? One of way I can imagine is adding this before the orginal filter line but I wonder if there is a better way

```scala
.filter(col("statusStandardizedData.isActive").isNotNull)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with datasets and case classes you can make the type of the fields optional with the Option[T] construct and subsequently check that the field is defined:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Option[Long])

val caseClassDS = Seq(Person("Andy", Some(32))).toDS()
caseClassDS
  .filter(_.age.getOrElse(0) > 30)
  .show()
```